# bing map api not giving proper response

Tags: javascript, html, maps, bing-maps

```
<Response xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/search/local/ws/rest/v1">
<Copyright>
Copyright © 2016 Microsoft and its suppliers. All rights reserved. This API cannot be accessed and the content and any results may not be used, reproduced or transmitted in any manner without express written permission from Microsoft Corporation.
</Copyright>
<BrandLogoUri>
http://dev.virtualearth.net/Branding/logo_powered_by.png
</BrandLogoUri>
<StatusCode>200</StatusCode>
<StatusDescription>OK</StatusDescription>
<AuthenticationResultCode>ValidCredentials</AuthenticationResultCode>
<TraceId>
48a2c46d66214527b6e6668db23d606d|HK20271744|02.00.153.400|CO30204710
</TraceId>
<ResourceSets>
<ResourceSet>
<EstimatedTotal>0</EstimatedTotal>
<Resources/>
</ResourceSet>
</ResourceSets>
</Response>
```

but the map is showing congestions and traffic jams in the specified location...

Comment: what do you asking, not clear

Comment: actually i am trying to get the traffic updates in my locality .....when i am checking it on bing maps it is showing the roads are congested but when i an running there REST API by giving my coordinates then it is not giving me correct information.......

Comment: i received the response Posted above...

Answer (score 0):

The Bing Maps Traffic API only returns incidents such as car accidents or construction and does not return any traffic flow information which is what you are seeing with the color coded roads on the map. This is why the response in the service isn't aligning with what you are seeing on the map.